# Is there any mistake in my code? Why my sponsor-slider row container does not take the full width by fluid

Tags: html

I am working with bootstrap 4. I have added a row with the class name `sponsor-slider-row`, also giving bootstrap call called `container-fluid` but nothing happen to like my row did not take the full width.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="sponsor-slider-row container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <section class="section-sponsor-slider">
        <h2 class="section-header">Sponsor Slider</h2>
        <div class="autoplay slider">
          <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code for us to figure out the problem

Comment: Are you sure this block of code isn't within a container already? It' should go full width OK.

Comment: @RogerWalsh Yes, it does not take the full width. you can check it from your end as well.

Comment: @KettyCelina may be your sponsor-slider-row and container-fluid  css contradicting to each other. Please provide your css also so we can analyze the actual issue

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. The example you have in the code snippet shows the row and column to be full width if you inspect the element? I'm guessing there is something in your css or that there is a parent container with a class of container?

Comment: I have added my all html and css. please help me to resolve this issue. I am copy pasting only relevent row html code.

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed have full width but your image is not sized to that, it is 150X150.  I added some garish borders to show this.
Note here I force a width on the images in the second group.

```css
.testme {
  border: solid 4px lime;
}

.myimgc,
.myimgc2 {
  border: solid 4px red;
}

.myimgc img,
.myimgc2 img {
  border: solid 4px cyan;
}

.myimgc img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="col-sm-12 sponsor-slider-row container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 testme">
      <section class="section-sponsor-slider">
        <h2 class="section-header">Sponsor Slider</h2>
        <div class="autoplay slider">
          <div class="myimgc2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-12 sponsor-slider-row container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 testme">
      <section class="section-sponsor-slider">
        <h2 class="section-header">Sponsor Slider</h2>
        <div class="autoplay slider">
          <div class="myimgc">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
          <div class="myimgc">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this does not answer your question please update your question to provide more information.

Answer (score -1):

```
HTML:
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../images/bg-pattern.png) repeat 50% 0
}

.section-header {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999.9rem
}

.site-header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: center
}

.site-header>div {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.site-header .site-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.site-header .site-title a {
  display: block;
  width: 30.6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  text-indent: -999.9rem;
  background: url(../images/advico-logo.png) no-repeat 0 0
}

.site-header .social-links {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 2.5rem
}

.site-header .social-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 7px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.3s
}

.site-header .social-links a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg)
}

.site-header .fa-facebook {
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #fff
}

.site-header .fa-facebook:hover {
  background: #3b5998
}

.site-header .fa-twitter {
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #fff
}

.site-header .fa-twitter:hover {
  background: #55acee
}

.dropnav {
  font-family: "montserrat", arial
}

.dropnav .navbar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #1a3364
}

.dropnav .navbar-brand {
  display: none
}

.dropnav .navbar-nav .nav-item a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff
}

.dropnav .navbar-nav .nav-item a:hover {
  color: #ccc
}

.dropnav .navbar-nav .nav-item.active a {
  color: #fff
}

.dropnav .navbar-toggler {
  z-index: 4;
  color: #d4882b;
  background: #d68224
}

.dropnav .form-control,
.dropnav .btn-outline-success {
  display: none
}

.section-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item .carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

.section-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-control .prev,
.section-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-control .next {
  color: #000
}

.landing-row.carousel-row .carousel-inner {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.landing-row.carousel-row .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  max-height: 40rem
}

.landing-row.carousel-row .carousel-inner .carousel-item img {
  width: 100%
}

.landing-row.main-matter-row {
  padding: 3rem 0.5rem;
  background: #eee
}

.sponsor-slider-row {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #db8323
}

.section-main-matter .section-header {
  position: static;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: 'montserrat', arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000
}

.section-main-matter .company-intro {
  font-family: 'montserrat', arial;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 200
}

.section-advertisement .map-sq-banner {
  text-align: center
}

.section-advertisement .map-sq-banner img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}

.site-footer {
  height: 100px;
  font-family: "montserrat", arial;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1a3364
}

.site-footer>div {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.site-footer .footer-text {
  padding: 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff
}

.site-footer .footer-text span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200
}

.section-sponsor-slider {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0
}

.section-sponsor-slider .slick-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.section-sponsor-slider .slick-next {
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Responsive Athletic</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?">

  <!-- Add icon library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<div class="body-container">

  <body>

    <div class="sponsor-slider-row container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <section class="section-sponsor-slider">
            <h2 class="section-header">Sponsor Slider</h2>
            <div class="autoplay slider">
              <div>
                <img src="images/sponsor-btn.png">
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="images/sponsor-btn.png">
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="images/sponsor-btn.png">
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="images/sponsor-btn.png">
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="images/sponsor-btn.png">
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="images/sponsor-btn.png">
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.autoplay').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      });
    </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: If this is indeed the answer to your question, please add notes saying WHY and how it does to assist others who may have the same issue.  If this is NOT intended as an answer, please update your question.

Comment: NOTE: This HTML is invalid. It is invalid to have a `<div class="body-container">` outside the `body` tag.